# replication level om Hadoop 3 cluster

Tags: hdfs, replication

I have hadoop 3.0 cluster (for study purpose), 1 name-node and 3 slaves.
On each node hdfs-site.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>/opt/hadoop/dfs/data</value>
        <final>true</final>
  </property>
  <property>
        <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
        <value>/opt/hadoop/dfs/name</value>
        <final>true</final>
  </property>
  <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I want 2 as replication levels for data.

But I see in Cluster WebUI

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08GS6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing those files were added before you changed the replication factor? Changing the default replication factor won't change any files that are currently stored on the cluster. To change those, run:

```
hadoop dfs -setrep -w 2 -R /user/data
```

Any new files you add should be automatically stored with a replication factor of 2.